# Slow sync of ShadowRepo to Public

Tags: ros, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had several people lately ask when I'm going to release my package on Kinetic. I just realized that it's been a month and hasn't migrated from the Shadow Fixed to the Public one. How long does this migration usually take?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253001/slow-sync-of-shadowrepo-to-public/) by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 276 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends, and varies based on regressions and other considerations. Usually it happens once every couple of months. Normally if you start a discussion on the release section of discourse.ros.org you can get the ball moving sooner than normal:

https://discourse.ros.org/c/release

Looking at the status page:

http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=REGRESSION

There doesn't appear to be any regressions right now, so a sync should be possible.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0